# Curious behaviour of std::string::operator[] in MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've been using some semi-iterators to tokenize a std::string, and I've run into a curious problem with operator[]. When constructing a new string from a position using char*, I've used something like the following:

```
t.begin = i;
t.end = i + 1;
t.contents = std::string(&arg.second[t.begin], &arg.second[t.end]);
```

where arg.second is a std::string. But, if i is the position of the last character, then `arg.second[t.end]` will throw a debugging assertion- even though taking a pointer of one-past-the-end is well defined behaviour and even common for primitive arrays, and since the constructor is being called using iterators I know that the end iterator will never be de-referenced. Doesn't it seem logical that `arg.second[arg.second.size()]` should be a valid expression, producing the equivalent of `arg.second.end()` as a char*?

Comment: Why don't you use the more idiomatics `arg.begin() + t.begin` and `arg.begin() + t.end` ?

Comment: @Alexandre: I just thought of that.

Comment: The string class has plenty of constructors, which might be more suitable, like `string ( size_t n, char c )` or `string ( const string& str, size_t pos, size_t n = npos )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not taking a pointer to one past the end, you're ACCESSING one past the end and then getting the address of that.  Entirely different and while the the former is well defined and well formed, the latter is not either.  I suggest using the iterator constructor, which is basically what you ARE using but do so with iterators instead of char*.  See Alexandre's comment.

Answer (score 3):

`operator[](size_type pos) const` doesn't return one-past-the-end is `pos` == size(); it returns `charT()`, which is a temporary.  In the non-`const` version of `operator[]`, the behavior is undefined.

21.3.4/1

> const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const;
>   reference operator[](size_type pos);
>   1 Returns: If pos < size(), returns data()[pos]. Otherwise, if pos == size(), the const
>   version returns charT(). Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

What is well-defined is creating an ***iterator*** one past the end. (Pointers might be iterators, too.) However, *dereferencing* such an iterator will yield *Undefined Behavior*.

Now, what you're doing is ***array subscription***, and that is very different from forming iterators, because it returns a reference to the referred-to object (much akin to *dereferencing* an iterator). You are certainly ***not allowed*** to access an array one-past-the-end.

Comment: Taking a pointer to one-past-the-end is fine, but that's not what the OP is actually doing.

Comment: @Mark: Which is what I said, no?

Comment: @sbi When I read the very first sentence of your answer, I assumed it applied to the quoted text, in other words that it *isn't* valid to take such a pointer.

Comment: @sbi: Maybe I misunderstand you, but taking a pointer to one-past-the-end is well-defined.

Comment: @sbi: The standard citations a spread out, but for example take a look at 5.7/5

Comment: @John: I wrote that creating one-passed-the-end iterators is fine and that pointers can be iterators, too. Then I wrote that what DeadMG does is different. What am I missing? Has "taking an iterator" a meaning fundamentally different from "creating an iterator"?

Comment: @Mark: I now could see how it was misleading. I removed the quote. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: @sbi:  My misnderstanding was the same as Mark's.  All's well now.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` is not an array. It is an object, whose interface loosely resembles an array (namely, provides `operator[]`). But that's when the similarity ends.

Even if we for a second assume that `std::string` is just a wrapper built on top of an ordinary array, then in order to obtain the one-past-the-end pointer for the stored sequence, you have to do something like `&arg.second[0] + t.end`, i.e. instead of going through the `std::string` interface first move into into the domain of ordinary pointers and use ordinary low-level pointer arithmetic.

However, even that assumption is not correct and doing something like `&arg.second[0] + t.end` is a recipe for disaster. `std::string` is not guaranteed to store its controlled sequence as an array. It is not guaranteed to be stored continuously, meaning that regardless of where your pointers point, you cannot assume that you'll be able to iterate from one to another by using pointer arithmetic.

If you want to use an `std::string` in some legacy pointer-based interface the only choice you have is to go through the `std::string::c_str()` method, which will generate a non-permanent array-based copy of the controlled sequence.

P.S. Note, BTW, that in the original C and C++ specifications it is illegal to use the `&a[N]` method to obtain the one-past-the-end pointer even for an ordinary built-in array. You always have to make sure that you are not using the `[]` operator with past-the-end index. The legal way to obtain the pointer has always been something like `a + N` or `&a[0] + N`, but not `&a[N]`. Recent changes legalized the `&a[N]` approach as well, but nevertheless originally it was not legal.

Comment: Not going to downvote you for this, but whether or not it was originally legal doesn't affect me in the slightest. My compiler is tagged in the OP - and it's a C++0x compiler. Pretty sure that I'm in the realm of recent changes. Secondly, it's my understanding that vector also used to be non-guaranteed contiguous storage, whereas it now is, along with string.

Comment: vector was guaranteed to be continuous.

Comment: @DeadMG: Firstly, as long as the question is tagged [C++], it is C++03 at most, not C++0x. If you want to talk about C++0x you have to state it explicitly. Just because you compiler "can do" C++0x if asked means nothing for a question explicitly tagged [C++]. (And the issue has nothing to do with C++0x, BTW). Secondly, indeed `std::vector` was not originally guaranteed to be continuous, which was just an accidental omission corrected later. `std::string` is not continuous and was never intended to be continuous.

Answer (score -1):

A string is not a primitive array, so I'd say the implementation is free to add some debug diagnostics if you are doing something dangerous like accessing elements outside its range. I would guess that a release build will probably work.

But...

For what you are trying to do, why not just use the `basic_string( const basic_string& str, size_type index, size_type length );` constructor to create the sub strings?

Comment: Release build may or may not work, it is still ultimately UB.

Comment: Yep, no disagreement there... I guess I could have been more clear on that.